# What is the difference between AT89C51 and AT89S51?

Tags: embedded, 8051

How do you connect these to your computer? Which one would be easier to burn?

Comment: Just FYI, stackoverflow is mainly geared toward programming questions.  You might consider posting this question at http://chiphacker.com/ which is more hardware related.

Comment: Closed, but this is related to "software development", in what way is it "far afield"?  I wonder if those voting to close are not embedded systems developers?

Comment: @Clifford - I agree; Ithink may programmers of small systems would find the answers of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information you seek can be found by comparing the data sheets: [AT89C51](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=1930), [AT89S51](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?family_id=604&family_name=8051+Architecture&part_id=1917), however you will see in this first link that it states:

> Not recommended for new designs. Use AT89S51.

So that probably makes your last question irrelevant, you should use the AT89S51 regardless.

With regard to your second question (which I interpret as "connecting to a development host"), I suggest that you use an off-the-shelf development board unless you have the means and skill to produce your own. In-system programming can be achieved through the UART (there's an app. note in the link above), so you'll need a PC with an RS-232 serial interface and a NULL-Modem cable (the latter may come with the board).  If you do not have a serial port on your PC, get a USB serial port adapter.

Obviously you need the development tools; at leas a compiler, and for debugging you'd benefit from an emulator; again the link above has references to tools.

Overall; read the manufacturer's documentation is the answer to all your questions! ;-)